# Xamarin Prism MasterDetailPage.IsPresented from child ViewModel

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, prism

Does anyone have a clue on how to control IsPresented property from a child view model?

I'm implementing a custom NavBar where I want to simulate the Hamburger icon behavior so my child page on load has

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

which hides the navigation par.

Inside Xaml file I have a button which I want to bind to a PropertyCommand of child viewmodel and show Master page, basically somehow to call Master's IsPresented.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to go about it.

The way I would do it would be to use MVVM and use an interface to access the 'presenting the Master page' functionality where its needed.

```
 public interface ICustomMasterDetail
 {
      void SetMasterPresented(bool isPresented);
 }
```

Now extend on the `MasterDetailPage` and also implement the above interface

```
public class CustomMasterDetail : MasterDetailPage, IRootMasterDetail
{
     public CustomMasterDetail() : base()
     {
        //constructor code
     }

     public void SetMasterPresented(bool isPresented)
     {
         IsPresented = isPresented;
     }
}
```

Using using an IoC container to register and resolve the interface will let you use its functionality from where ever you want.

The other solution would be to just use a static variable to store the instance of your MasterDetailPage and access that directly to change the `IsPresented` property

Comment: Thanks Skar, this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Thanks @skar, I am looking for similar solution. What does this mean - "using an IoC container to register and resolve the interface" 
New to xamarin here.. please help

Comment: Using IoC you would need to ensure that you are resolving the same instance that is already presented on screen. Otherwise you would end up with a separate copy in memory and nothing happens on screen.

Comment: @der_michael any idea on how to access that instance in Prism. I am using Prism navigation and custom title bar. I want to set the MasterMenu.IsPresented on click of button in custom title bar. I have also asked this question here  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267942/how-to-show-menu-in-masterdetail-page-when-using-prism-and-custom-title-bar

Comment: I'm using MessagingCenter to post a notification that my view model controlling `IsPresented` is subscribed to.

Comment: thank you @der_michael, we ended up re-writing the navigation all together. Ofcourse MessagingCenter!! *faceplams*. I will be trying this out soon and let you know.